# klee with loops strange behaviour with similar code

Tags: llvm-gcc, klee, symbolic-computation

I have a question about how is working KLEE (symbolic execution tool) in case of loops with symbolic parameters:

```
int loop(int data) {
  int i, result=0;
  for (i=0;i<data ;i++){   
     result+= 1;
     //printf("result%d\n", result); //-- With this line klee give different values for data
}
   return result;
}
void main() {
  int n;
  klee_make_symbolic(&n, sizeof(int),"n");  
  int result=loop(n) ;
}
```

If we execute klee with this code, it give only one test-case.
However, if we  take out the comment of the printf(...), klee will need some type of control for stop the execution, because it will produce values for n:
--max-depth= 200

I would like to understand why klee have this different behavior, that doesn't have sense for me. Why if I don't have a printf in this code, it will not produce the same values.

I discovered that it happens whend the option --optimize  is used
when it is not there is the same behavior. Someone know how is working the --optimize of Klee?

An another quieston about the same is, if in the paper that they have published, As I understand they said that their heuristics search will make it not be infinite (they useavoid starvation)
 because I have it runing  doesn't stop, It is true that should finish the klee execution in case of this loop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you compile your source into LLVM ? Do you use clang or gcc front end?

Comment: llvm-gcc -g -v --emit-llvm -c loop.c  And then: klee --allow-external-sym-calls --optimize loop.o . But if I take out the --optimize then the loop do always the same, with or without the printf it comes infinite execution. What I want to know is why this different behavior with the option --optimize. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is why this different behavior with the option
>   --optimize. Thanks

In C/C++ there is concept of "undefined behaviour" (see: A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, [Part1](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213),[Part 2](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/226),[Part 3](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/232), What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior [[#1/3]](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html),[[#2/3]](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html),[[#3/3]](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html)).

Overflow of `signed` integer is defined as *undefined behaviour* in order to allow compiler to do optimize stuff like this:

```
bool f(int x){ return x+1>x ? true : false ; }
```

let's think... x+1>x in normal algebra is always true, in this modulo algebra it is almost always true (except one case of overflow), so let's turn it into:

```
true
```

Such practices enables huge amount of great optimizations. (Btw. If you want to have defined behaviour when overflow, use `unsigned` integers - this feature is extensively used in cryptography algorithms implementations).

On the other hand, sometimes leads to surprising results,
like this code:

```
int main(){
    int s=1, i=0;
    while (s>0) {
        ++i;
        s=2*s;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Being optimised into infinite loop. It's not bug! It's powerful feature! (Again.. for defined behaviour , use `unsigned`).

Let's generate assembly codes for above examples:

```
$ g++ -O1 -S -o overflow_loop-O1.s overflow_loop.cpp
$ g++ -O2 -S -o overflow_loop-O2.s overflow_loop.cpp
```

Check of loop part is compiled differently:

overflow_loop-O1.s:

```
(...)
.L2:
    addl    $1, %eax
    cmpl    $31, %eax
    jne    .L2
(...)
```

overflow_loop-O2.s:

```
(...)
.L2:
    jmp    .L2
(...)
```

I would advice you to check assembly of your code on different optimisation levels (`gcc -S -O0` vs `gcc -S -O1`...`-O3`).
And again, nice posts about topic:
[[1]](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213),
[[2]](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/226),
[[3]](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/232),
[[4]](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html),
[[5]](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html),
[[6]](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html).